# Understanding the package drawing of a qfp

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, altium, tqfp

I am designing my very first PCB and there are a few things on the package drawing of my microcontroller that are unclear to me.

[image]

- Why are the sizes expressed in fractions? 
  e.g.: 0,23/0,13 or 0,75/0,45. What does each element stand for
- What do TYP and SQ stand for?

side question related to the previous one: I am looking for the length of a

[image]

is it calculated by: (16,10-12,40)/2 or  (15,90-12,40)/2?

Comment: TYP = Typical, SQ = Square. The pairs of figures aren't fractions, but maximum/minimum sizes (in mm)

Comment: @BrianDrummond, how should I interprete the word "square"?

Comment: Uh, it means square. For example the 16.1mm dimension applies to both the width and length of the chip.

Comment: Those are not fractions, they are maximum/minimum dimensions. TYP is an abbreviation for "typical". SQ in this context means the dimension refers to the square package (not the beveled corners). And this drawing is actually called a package drawing, not a schematic.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, oh you mean square like "square mm" to describe the area?

Comment: @MarkU, why are they using maximum and minimum dimension? Don't tell me that those engineers are able to fit a zillion transistors inside a cpu but anable to be more precise than 1mm when designing a package.

Comment: The package is square - 14 mm by 14 mm (+/-0.05 mm).  They just show the horizontal measurements , and tell you that the vertical measurements are the same.

Comment: The min/max values are there because of mechanical tolerances during manufacturing which the engineers that designed the internals of the IC really have no control over.

Comment: Somewhere near the page you're on, our should see page with the recommended land pattern, which is what you should use to design your pcb.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, this is the datasheet:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms433b/spms433b.pdf
Unfortunately there doesn t seem to be anything called "land pattern"

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spma056&ved=0ahUKEwjc7qvR9cjLAhWGKx4KHa9XC9MQFggnMAU&usg=AFQjCNH7GJ8ZIHQYTzirYYeRLgGmqhBbhQ&sig2=mAOj4a0G--lj7GtU7pSnQg  page 5

Comment: It gives dimensions and points to a standard

Comment: Even though the integrated circuit may be fabricated using photolithography with dimensional tolerances of a fraction of a micrometer, the external leadframe is manufactured using a completely different process (stamped from a piece of sheetmetal, several "chips" per frame). After wafer sort, each good die is mounted onto a section of the leadframe and a wire bonding machine welds the bond wires between special exposed pads on the top surface of the die and the leadframe. Finally the die is encapsulated in epoxy, forming the plastic package, and each chip is cut free of the rest of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments

TYP = Typical, this is used to label a feature that is to be interpreted as exactly the same as nearby comparable features, i.e. the distance between pins are the same in all sides.

SQ = Square, this means the package is square and the four sides have the same size.

Dimensions are given as maximum/minimum in mm.